# npm installs optional dependency 'chromedriver' for no reason

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

I am on NPM version 5.8.0, I ran this command:

```
npm install --no-optional --silent
```

chromedriver is declared as an optional dep:

```
 "optionalDependencies": {
    "chromedriver": "^2.35.0"
  },
```

when I ran the install command, npm installed chromedriver, and I can't figure out why.

to check if something else depends on chromedriver, I ran:

```
$ npm la chromedriver
cdt-now@0.1.12
│ /Users/alexamil/WebstormProjects/nabisco/cdt-now
│ 
└── chromedriver@2.35.0 
    ChromeDriver for Selenium
    git://github.com/giggio/node-chromedriver.git
    https://github.com/giggio/node-chromedriver
```

is this just a bug with NPM version 5.8.x?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a [pending issue](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/17633) with npm right now:

According to the github issue thread, a temporary workaround would be to use no-shrinkwrap like this:

```
--production --no-shrinkwrap
```

But do note that the collateral from doing this is that the `package-lock.json` file would not be taken into account.